# Is there anyway to find the values for equation with two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Is there mathematical anyway to find the values for equation with two variables? as example:

I have y = (20x+3)r+x and **y** is 50. then what is **x** and **r** values?

Answer (score 2):

No. The equation with two variables $x$ and $r$

$$y=50=(20x+3)r+x$$
has infinitely many solutions.
Notice that the equation is equivalent to
$$(20r+1)x=50-3r$$
so if we pick $r\ne-\frac1{20}$ we find $x=\frac{50-3r}{20r+1}$.

Comment: What if I want real numbers only as values?

Comment: @Kumar: Are you saying that for some real $r$, Sami's formula for $x$ is not real??

Comment: sorry I mean Integer numbers

Comment: as example if y is 50 there is no Integer numbers for both r and x, but if y = 217, there is Integer numbers can solve the equation: r = 5 and x = 2 –

Comment: Nicely done Sami!

Answer (score 0):

There are three unknowns in your problem, namely $x,y,r$ and you only have two equations. So, here $$50=(20x+3)r+x$$ gives you a relation between $r$ and $x$. For example, assuming that $(20x+3) \ne 0$,$$r=\frac{50-x}{20 x+3}$$ you can select any $x$ and get avalue for $r$.

Comment: Is there anyway to know if any Integer numbers can solve the equation?

Comment: Yes there is. Put $x=50$, then $r=50-x=0$, which is a real number.

Comment: sorry, I mean Integer numbers large than 0

Answer (score 0):

$y = (20x+3)r+x = 20xr+3r+x\\ 20y+3 = (20x+3)(20r+1)$

So you should find the factors of $20y+3$.

Comment: @Micael: thanks, but what "try to factor" mean?